# For loop stops iterating in recursive function

Tags: python, for-loop, recursion, directed-acyclic-graphs

I'm attempting to solve the [dependency hell](https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/codeagon/challenges/dependency-hell) problem on Hackerrank using Python 2.7.

I have formed a dictionary which lists all the dependencies. This is how the dictionary looks:

```
d = {1: [1, 8], 2: [0], 3: [1, 7], 4: [1, 7], 5: [1, 2], 6: [1, 2], 7: [0], 8: [2, 3, 4]}
```

The first number in each of the lists is just the number of elements in that list. The next numbers are the indices of the dependencies. Each number is the index for a software (i.e. software #1).

I've tried to create a recursive function that given an index, would list all the SW that need to be installed for the intended SW to be installed. I'm not worrying about the order at this point. This is the function:

```
def listSW(p,d,L):
    L.append(p)
    if d[p][0] > 0:
        for i in xrange(1,d[p][0]+1):
            return listSW(d[p][i],d,L)
    else:
        return L
```

Where `L` is a list (initially empty) where I'm dumping the indices of everything that needs to be installed and `p` is the software we intend to install.

The problem is that in the `for` loop only `i = 1` is ever considered. So if I run the function for `p = 8` I get:

```
[8, 3, 7]
```

When I intend to get:

```
[8, 3, 7, 4, 7]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: your `for` loop will return at the first iteration, so it can't loop at all - you need to change it so the `return` is not part of the loop

Comment: I was under the impression that once I hit return it would just conclude `i = 1` and move on to `i = 2`. How would I be able to consider all cases here?

Comment: `return` "quits" the function - it does not have any special meaning inside a loop. I'm not entirely certain what that function is supposed to do, but you probably want to store the result of all recursive calls in a list (maybe `L.append(listSW(d[p][i],d,L))`?) and then `return` it **after** your loop is finished

Comment: Once you return you're preventing further calls in the loop to be made, that's why you end up having missing dependencies.

Comment: Just deleted `return` and it fixed it. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def listSW(p,d,L):
    L.append(p)
    if d[p][0] > 0:
        for i in xrange(1,d[p][0]+1):
            listSW(d[p][i],d,L)
    return L
```

But I prefer not mixing return and updating a list so, I would do :

```
def buildList(p,d,L=[]):
    def patchList(p,d,L):
        L.append(p)
        for i in d[p][1:]:
            patchList(i,d,L)
    patchList(p,d,L)
    return L
```